# How do I establish a gradient (drawable) as status bar color?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

How to do I establish a gradient as status bar background for Android Studio.

.

Answer (score 2):

drawable/gradient.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
    android:startColor="#FF00FF00" />
</shape>
```

This's sample, you can fix endColor and startColor the same color

layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/test"
```